# How can i Test my react app within Microsoft Teams to ensure that its works as expected

Tags: reactjs, node.js, teams-toolkit

how can i use Microsoft Teams’ developer preview feature to test my app during development

i wanted created a react and nodejs app and integrated in ms teams

If there is a free way to integrate a react app in ms teams just for test

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out. To access the developer preview for Teams, please follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro).

You can test a react app in Teams for free, as long as you have a [Microsoft 365 developer account](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program). This will allow you to try out your app without any cost.